# Using SharePoint lists in DAL instead of a database (with caching)

Tags: caching

I am planning to utilize SharePoint lists in a custom solution. I would like content managers to make updates to the lists, and then publish the changes.

The lists would be accessed from DAL which creates DAL objects from list rows. DAL is referenced by BLL which is referenced by WCF which exposes the BLL objects through an IRepository to clients via REST and SOAP.

When content managers want to update values in the lists they just make the updates and publish the changes with a simple custom publishing feature which refreshes the cache with fresh data from the lists.

I would like to hear if ready-made solutions exist for this, whether I can reuse some existing APIs for caching lists (SP APIs?). How to refresh cache on all the front-ends?

Comment: What "cache" on WFE did you specifically have in mind? Some OOTB SharePoint caching, or perhaps something totally custom? How are you accessing the items that are "cached" on the WFE?

Comment: I am talking about totally custom caching. I would incorporate SharePoint list access in DAL, and deliver cached custom BLL objects to clients via WCF. (Users could perhaps have the possibility to publish changes via a simple SharePoint publishing feature which does refresh the cache.)

Comment: rewrote the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a lot like the Patterns and Practices Entity Framework to me...

Also have a look at this: [Simple data access pattern for SharePoint lists](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2008/11/simple-data-access-pattern-for.html)

And this: [MSDN: The Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413961.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Ended up making a repository which creates BLLs both from from sql (from oob sql entity framework) and sp (with additional layers for easy and fast access).